# How to use Objective-C NSMeasurement category methods in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, foundation

Let's assume we have a category on `NSMeasurement` in our project.

The .h file (the .m file does also exists):

```
NSMeasurement+Test.h

@interface NSMeasurement (Test)

- (NSString *)foo;

@end
```

Now let's further assume that we have a Swift class where we want to use the category method `foo`. The problem here is that `NSMeasurement` will be "transformed" into the Measuement class in Swift.
And yes, the category header has been inserted into the Brinding header file.

The question is: How can i access the NSMeasurement func "foo" although it has been "mutated" to an Measurement class in swift

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, what the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you have to use `NSMeasurement` or you can type cast `Measurement` into `NSMeasurement`.

```
let measurement = Measurement(value: 20, unit: Unit(symbol: "kg")) as NSMeasurement
let value = measurement.foo()
print(value)
```

According to [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6) `NSMeasurement` can be bridged into `Measurement` but they are in fact separate things. `NSMeasurement` is a `class` while `Measurement` is a `struct`.

If it would be same class then it was straight forward implementation. 
For example: if you create an extension of `UITableView` in `Objective C` then you can directly access extension methods it in `Swift`.